# After upgrade to Laravel 5.1: must be of the type array, object given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

After I upgraded from Laravel 4 to 5.0+ to Laravel 5.1 I got this error:

```
Argument 2 passed to Collective\Html\HtmlBuilder::{closure}() must be of the type array, object given ... macros.php', '92', array('items' => object(Collection)))
```

So I checkt the macros.php

```
/**
* Render Dropdown Options
*/
HTML::macro('dropdownOptions', function(Collection $items, array selected, $withEmpty = true, $render = false)
{
$options = null;

/* jQuery Plugin 'choosen' needs an empty option as
 * default selection */
if ($withEmpty)
{
    $options = '<option></option>';
}

$items->each(function($item) use(&$options, $selected)
{
    $options .= sprintf('<option %s value="%s">%s</option>',
        (in_array($item->id, $selected)) ? 'selected="selected"' : '',
        $item->id,
        $item->name
    );
});

if ($render)
{
    echo $options;
}

return $options;
});
```

And my helper File:

```
use HTML;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DropdownHelper
{
public static function getOptions($type, $selected = array())
{
    return HTML::dropdownOptions(self::get(new $type), $selected);
}

public static function getGroupedOptions($type, $selected = array(), $childPropertyName = 'services')
{
    return HTML::groupedDropdownOptions(self::get(new $type), $selected, $childPropertyName);
}

protected static function get(Model $model)
{
    return $model::all();
}
}
```

But i don't get it, I checked the composer.json and the providers also the Aliases. All looks good for me. Why I got this error?

DropdownHelper::getOptions:

```
$view
->with('optionsSalutation', DropdownHelper::getOptions(
            DropdownEntityEnum::Salutations, $view->selectedOptionSalutation))
->nest('profileImageSection', 'customer.partials.profileimage', array('image' => $view->image));
```

UserProfileController:

```
$data = array_merge(Auth::user()->profile->toArray(), array(
        'view'                              => 'customer.account.profile.private',
        'type'                              => Auth::user()->getTypeId(),
        'selectedOptionSalutation'          => [Auth::user()->profile->getSalutationId()],
        'image'                             => Auth::user()->profile->image,
        'has_newsletter'                    => Auth::user()->getHasNewsletter()
    ));
```

Comment: What is `$view->selectedOptionSalutation` assigned to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error shows that the `items` you're passing in is a `Collection` instance. It needs to be an array.

So, I'm guessing that wherever you're calling `DropdownHelper::getOptions()`, the second parameter being passed in is a `Collection`. Call `->all()` on that `Collection` to get the underlying array.

Comment: e.g `$request->all()` on my case

Answer (score -2):

i think replacing

```
$selected = array()
```

with

```
$selected = []
```

should work.
in laravel 4 you needed to use array() function, but in newer version you can use [].